# hello, I can't upload my project to heroku, it says I don't have a file pom.xml but I have

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

> I get this error

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/java
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack- 
registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/java.tgz
   Could not find a pom.xml file! Please check that it exists and is committed to Git.
   More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
!     Push failed
```

> But I have pom.xml in my project https://github.com/Nurba1713/e-book.git

> Maybe this is a very stupid question, I apologize in advance, I am a beginner and self-taught.

Comment: You mean heroku right? No hiroku

Comment: According to git, your pom is in a subfolder, not the root folder. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POM file must be in the root of the repository, see [Heroku Java guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#declare-app-dependencies)